# resize an image in 'a href' tag link

Tags: html, image, resize

looking at the code below, i can show an image with a smaller size

```
<a href="images/image.jpg"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="300" height="214" border="0"></a>
```

but what if i want the href link to show the image with a smaller size as well.  so lets say the original image.jpg is 1500x1200 and in the link i want to show it 800x600.

is there anyway to do something like this:

```
<a href="images/image.jpg" width="800" height="600"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="300" height="214" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Please don't — http://offog.org/articles/image-scaling/ — have different URLs with images scaled to different sizes. Downloading a 1500x1200 image for display at 800x600 or 300x214 is (at best) a horrible waste of bandwidth and time.

Comment: … and don't forget the mandatory alt attribute (on the subject of which: the border attribute has been deprecated, use CSS instead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to control the size of the image that is the target of the `href`, using attributes of the `a` tag?

You can't do that. Your best bet (for controlling the size from the source of the link) is to serve your images using a server-side script which accepts size parameters in a querystring. Like `image.php?img=image.jpg&w=800&h=600`.

But that's a whole other question and would be out of scope for me to go into detail here.

Of course if you want to just change the image to a particular size, just resize the actual image and upload it again :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a funny solution:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='<img src=images/image.jpg width=800 height=600>'"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="300" height="214" border="0"></a>
```

Though personally I would not recommend it, it works. :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the meaning of each part. Can you explain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

since you open the image itself it is impossible.

what you can do is,

link to and empty html page with only an `<img src="URL" width="" height=""/>` and apply the size to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out image-resizer in nodejs.

Here's the link: https://github.com/jimmynicol/image-resizer

Or you can use cloudinary nodejs integration which provides a free tier access for first 7500 image transformations